# Take my cat on a trip to the mountain house for 3 days or leave at home?

Tags: cats, travel

I have a cat and I know they get very anxious while left at home for a while or taken to a strange place. **However, I have family members that can come over once a day to feed and clean her litter box.**

I have two options. Take my cat on an hour and a half drive to a mountain house where she has never been for 3 days. OR I could leave my cat at my house and have family take care of her each day.
Side note: my cat has never been to a strange place besides the occasional vet visit.

Comment: Does your cat know your family members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By my experience, she should stay at home but leave her toys that have treats hidden inside or hide treats in her toys so your cat has some entertainment. Leave the cat-flap open and leave some food in her bowl when you leave! Hope this helped!

Answer (score 3):

My mum in law has a cat that loves to travel, she'll just jump into the car while she goes for short trips to the shops and everything lol
it really just depends on how your cat reacts to car trips and also how she reacts to being alone, how old is she?
Cats generally don't like being away from their owners too long but every cat is different so I'd just weigh out what she would react to best and decide on that
It could be a bonding experience for her if you did take her but honestly whatever you feel she is comfortable with is your best option
Hope this helps
Safe travels :)